# JSF - Updating a JSF datatable on page refresh

Tags: jsf, jpa-2.0

I have a datatable on my JSF page, which gets filled dynamically on page load thanks to BalusC and Odelya.
But now when I try to refresh the JSF page to retrieve the updated data from database, I don't get the updated data in the Datatable.

I have already gone through the following link but couldn't understand the nuances..!

[JSF datatable refresh on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276858/jsf-datatable-refresh-on-page-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your bean scope configured as a Session?

Have you tried to change its scope to Request?

Don't forget to close your connection after filling your resultset, which has to be a [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)

Here is an example from Core JavaServer Faces book:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydb")
    private DataSource ds;

    public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers");
            CachedRowSet crs = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
            crs.populate(result);
            return crs;
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked.. I changed the scope of managed bean from Session to Request..! If u don't mind, can u please tell me the basic difference between Request and Session Scoped Beans..! Thanks..! :)

Comment: Session scope keep the model's data stored while the session is active. You can specify how much time it's gonna stay alive in your web.xml (search for <session-config> and <session-timeout> tags). This is a good way to store some data, like a shopping cart in a virtual store. The session is stored in the server, and it usually uses cookies on the client side, to tie your client to the session.
Meanwhile, the request scope has a short life. It starts in the request and ends after the response is sent back. No data will be kept. Every new request will construct your bean again.

Answer (score 0):

```
'@RequestScoped' should be added to refresh your bean File to get the new data.
```